# Sequelize - Getter changing order of properties

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, getter-setter, getter

So I'll start this by acknowledging that I understand and agree that the order of a property is meaningless and generally of no real consequence.  But I'm an idiot.

I recently made a change in a Sequelize model that performs some ho-hummery (via get(){}) on a db column before returning it.  As soon as I applied the getter, that particular property floated to the top of the json representation of the object.  Merely running through the getter without changing the value causes this effect.

The objects in my project were created to "group" and "order" these properties in some sort of natural order, so I'm a bit annoyed by this behavior.

Besides a psychiatric visit, does anyone have suggestions on how to deal with this?

Example section of model:

```
        thingie: {
            field: "Thingie",
            type: DataTypes.STRING(1000),
            validate: {
                len: {
                    args: 8,
                    msg: `Thingie must be at least 8 characters long`
                }
            },
            get() {
                return this.getDataValue('thingie');
            },
            set(value) {
                this.setDataValue('thingie', value);
            }
        }
```

The only change to the model was the addition of the getter and setter.

Result before:

```json
{
    "id": "184b1feb-87de-4362-836d-6221eada3a67",
    "junk": "bobsyouruncle",
    "emailAddress": "bobs@uncle.com",
    "thingie": "supersafe",
    "createdAt": "2022-02-10T00:19:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-10T00:19:00.000Z"
}
```

Result with getter / setter:

```json
{
    "thingie": "supersafe",
    "id": "184b1feb-87de-4362-836d-6221eada3a67",
    "junk": "bobsyouruncle",
    "emailAddress": "bobs@uncle.com",
    "createdAt": "2022-02-10T00:19:00.000Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-02-10T00:19:00.000Z"
}
```

Comment: Can you show a field definition before and after adding a getter and examples of both JSON?

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: How do you get JSON for a model instance?

Comment: As very systematic person, I share your frustration with this!

Comment: @SaroMarcarian, did you managed to solve this?